# Liberty Basic Payroll Calculator IF ELSE

Tags: calculator, basic

I'm just getting started with learning basic programming with Sams and already am having issues with the simple payroll calculator I've been trying to write. Could someone explain how I could better rewrite this? And can you only follow IF THEN statements with a print command? I think I'll have to invest in a newer book but I was hoping I could get this to run at least in the meantime.

```
Input "Please input payrate: "; Ans$
    Print
Input "Please input hours worked: "; Hrs$
If (Hrs$ >= "40") Then
    payRate = (Hrs$ * Ans$)
Else If (Hrs$ <= "41") Then
    payRate = Hrs$ * (1.5 * Ans$)
End If

taxRate = payRate * .15
grossPay = payRate * Hrs$
netPay = payRate - taxRate

Print

Print: "Your net pay is: "; netPay
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, I see you have an `else if` statement. One of the perplexing design decisions in Liberty Basic is that it doesn't support the `else if`/`elseif` statement that you might find in most BASIC language dialects.

From the [online manual](https://www.libertybasicuniversity.com/lb4help/):

> The `elseif` keyword is not supported.  Here is an >example using `elseif` (QBasic):

```
  'QBasic only

  if sis boom bah then
    print "Yippie!"
  elseif la dee da then
    print "So what!"
  end if
```

> Instead in Liberty BASIC, it looks like this:

```
  'Liberty BASIC - no elseif

  if sis boom bah then
    print "Yippie!"
  else
    if la dee da then
      print "So what!"
    end if
  end if
```

And to extend the above official documentation a little further with my own code sample in LB (Liberty Basic), you might just appreciate how deeply nested the `if`, `else`, `end if` can become.

```
 'Liberty BASIC

 grade = 55

  if grade > 90 then
    print "Excellent!"
  else
    if grade > 80 and grade < 90 then
        print "Good"
     else
        if grade > 70 and grade < 80 then
            print "We need to try a little harder."
        else
            if grade > 60 and grade < 70 then
                print "We need to try a lot harder!"
            else
                print "Let's have a talk."
            end if
         end if
     end if
  end if
end
```

The equivalent in another dialect of BASIC, in this case FreeBasic, might look something like this which of course appears much tidier with only one `end if` *vs* a trail of `end if`'s:

```
'FreeBasic 

Dim grade as integer = 55

  if grade > 90 then
      print "Excellent!"
  elseif grade > 80 and grade < 90 then
      print "Good"
  elseif grade > 70 and grade < 80 then
      print "We need to try a little harder."
  elseif grade > 60 and grade < 70 then
      print "We need to try a lot harder!"
  else
      print "Let's have a talk."
  end if
sleep
end
```

But all is not lost with LB because the language actually implements a fairly powerful `select case` statement which can include conditional statements which is not possible in certain dialects of BASIC (*i.e.* PureBasic)

```
'LB - Liberty Basic

grade = 55

select case grade
    case grade > 90
        print "Excellent!"
    case (grade > 80) and (grade < 90)
        print "Good"
    case (grade > 70) and (grade < 80)
        print "We need to try a little harder."
    case (grade > 60) and (grade < 70)
        print "We need to try a lot harder!"
    case else
        print "Let's have a talk."
end select
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Liberty, but I imagine it's complaining when you're trying to do math on strings.  Additionally, I find your misuse of the "payrate" name to be confusing. The logic of the overtime calc is also wrong.  Here's my first attempt at a rewrite:

```
Input "Please input payrate: "; Rate$
Rate = val(Rate$)
Print
Input "Please input hours worked: "; Hrs$
Hrs = val(Hrs$)
Gross = Hrs * Rate
If Hrs > 40 Then Gross = Gross + ((Hrs - 40) * Rate / 2))
Taxes = Gross * .15
Net = Gross - Taxes
Print
Print: "Your gross pay is: "; Gross
Print: "Your net pay (after $";Taxes;" in taxes) is: "; Net
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work in Liberty BASIC:

```
INPUT "Please enter hours worked: "; hours 'you don't need a dollar sign at the end of the variable because it's a value not a string
INPUT "Please enter your hourly rate: "; hourlyRate
gross = hours * hourlyRate 'works out the gross amount
IF (hours > 40) THEN 'if the person worked more than 40 hours, then the following command is applicable...
gross = 40 * hourlyRate + ((hours - 40) * (hourlyRate * 1.5)) 'this line calculates the money earned for 40 hours, and adds the remaining hours at 1.5 times the hourly rate
END IF 'end the IF condition
tax = gross * 0.15 'calculates the tax at 15%
net = gross - tax 'calculates the net pay (i.e., gross pay after tax)
PRINT "-------------------------------"
PRINT "Your gross pay is: "; gross
PRINT "Your net pay is: "; net
```

As the previous poster suggested, you should use values instead of strings for maths (values don't have a dollar sign at the end), and when you label your variables they should have a meaningful name in relation to what you're trying to achieve.

Liberty BASIC has a tutorial under Help that you can use to teach yourself how to code. Otherwise Beginning Programming for Dummies is another useful guide - that's what I'm using :)